# Does interacting with cameras "do" anything?

Tags: borderlands-2

Every so often I come across cameras like this one:

[image: Borderlands2Camera]

They open up when I get close, and it seems I need to get within a certain radius to "activate" them.  However, once they are "activated" it doesn't seem like anything else happens.  Does interacting with them cause any other effect?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are just checkpoint markers.  When you activate one, you'll notice the Borderlands logo appear on screen indicating that your progress is being saved.  When you die, you will be resurrected at the latest one you activated.

Comment: Technically they're also New-U stations, just not interactive like the ones you use for fast travel. In the first game you could change your colours and save file name and also respec at the fast travel ones as well, but in Borderlands 2 those functions have been offloaded to the Quick Change stations (like that one outside Pierce Station in Sanctuary).